# Cannot show static image in assets on dynamic router-link

Tags: vue.js, dynamic

I have a route /member/:id, and on this route there is a image need to be show. I try with static image first like this:

```
<v-img src="@/assets/photos/Nan.jpeg"/>
```

or 
but It does not show anything or a small broken image icon.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOzkL.png)
In vue extension of chrome, it contains:
currentSrc: http://localhost:8080/member/img/Nan.93326bd3.jpeg
I cannot see the photo on this path
but I can see on http://localhost:8080/img/Nan.93326bd3.jpeg.
I guess the error related to "/member/"

I also try with "require and :src" or "import" image, but it didn't work.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

We store the images in `/public/images` , so if you store an image with file name myImage.png at images folder, you can do:

```
<v-img src="/images/myImage.png"/>
```